# spring - Unsatisfied dependency expressed through object property

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, spring.net

I am receiving the following error when attempting to inject my dao into a unit test class using spring.

```
UnitTest.DataAccess.FruitDaoTest.GetAllVitaminC:
SetUp : Spring.Objects.Factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException : Error creating object with name 'FruitDaoTest' : Unsatisfied dependency expressed through object property 'FruitDao': Set this property value or disable dependency checking for this object.
```

Here is the segment of my spring config file that is relevant:

```xml
<db:provider
    id="DbProvider"
    provider="SqlServer-2.0"
    connectionString="Data Source=stuff.group.stuff;Initial Catalog=zing;User ID=Marve; Password=stinky" />

<object id="transactionManager" type="Spring.Data.Core.AdoPlatformTransactionManager, Spring.Data">
  <property name="DbProvider" ref="DbProvider" />
</object>
<object id="FruitDao" type="FruitBasket.DataAccess.FruitDao, FruitBasket">
  <property name="DbProvider" ref="DbProvider"/>
  <property name="user" value="apple" />
  <property name="pass" value="orange" />
  <property name="server" value="pear" />
</object>
```

I'm not very familiar with spring so I'm unsure of what the problem is here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your test does not use the context where you defined your FruitDao bean, thus preventing its autowiring... Check the GetContext/ConfigLocations methods to be sure you load the expected XML files.